# Can I list to which projects I ever contributed?

Tags: github

Is it possible to get a complete list of all GitHub projects (repositories) I ever contributed to?

I know that I can see the latest 5 on my home page, but I would like to get a complete list. It would be nice if that would work for other users, too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. Github has [APIs for this kind of stuff](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-events-performed-by-a-user), but they mention this:

> Events support pagination, however the per_page option is unsupported. The fixed page size is 30 items. Fetching up to ten pages is supported, for a **total of 300 events**.
>
> Only events created within the past 90 days will be included in timelines. Events **older than 90 days will not be included** (even if the total number of events in the timeline is less than 300).

There's no "show me all repositories I've contributed to" API, and all other APIs are based around the repo resource. That is, per project, not per user.